# Counting partitions of a finite set excluding singletons

Tags: combinatorics, bell-numbers

I am not a combinatorialist by training, but I need insight on the following question for a current project.  I cannot find this as a duplicate here.

Let $[n]$ be the set $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$.  I want to count certain partitions of $[n]$.  I wish for no ordering of my cells or within my cells. I think I am correct in that the Bell number $B_n$ counts this for me.  So, for $[5]$, the Bell number $B_5=52$ takes into account that the two partitions
$$
\{1, 2, 4\}, \{3\}, \{5\}
$$
versus 
$$
\{3\}, \{1, 2, 4\}, \{5\}
$$
are counted as the same, and there are then 52 distinct partitions.  Correct?

This is close to what I need, but not quite.  My problem is:  **Count the number of partitions of $[n]$ in which no cell is a singleton.**  Call this count $B^*_n$ for the lack of any good notation.

By nothing clever, just brute force, I have example calculations

\begin{array}{c c c}
n & B_n & B^*_n\\\hline
3 & 5 & 1\\
4 & 15 & 4\\
5 & 52 & 11\\
\end{array}

I've tried getting $B^*_n$ from $B_n$ by in/exclusion, but this is not going well for me.  I've also tried to find some recurrence, but I am just as stuck there.  Does anyone have any insight or a reference for this count?  I would take just about anything, even some asymptotics.

Edit:  a paper in the OEIS link below proves via generating functions that 
$$
B^*_{n+1} = B_n - B^*_n
$$
and this is not clear to me at all.  Is this deep?

Comment: Have you looked at comments/formulas in https://oeis.org/A000110?

Comment: I've not.  Will...

Comment: https://oeis.org/A000296 may be what you want.

Comment: Wow.  Yes, it is.  I have a lot to wade through...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an easy combinatorial proof for $B_{n+1}^* = B_n - B_{n}^*$.
Note that $B_n - B_{n}^*$ is the number of partitions of $[n]$ that have at least one singleton. Take all elements that are in singletons and add $n+1$ to that to form a part in a partition of $[n+1]$ that has no singletons. This is clearly a bijection.

Answer (score 1):

The Maxima program in https://oeis.org/A000296 looks to be the clearest way to produce what you want.